# Can an Israeli and and American fulfill havdalah after Shabbos the first day of Yom Tov together?

Tags: shabbat, eretz-yisrael, yom-tov, chutz-laaretz, havdalah

Inspired by [this answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/86036/11532) and the comments following.

If the first day of Yom Tov (not Rosh Hashana) is Shabbos, an Israeli will make a normal havdalah המבדיל בין קדש לחול, while someone from outside Israel will make havdalah during kiddush המבדיל בין קדש לקדש.

Can either of them be yotzei by listening to the other?  Or do they still have to make their own correct havdalah?

I'm interested in both the lechatchila and bedieved answers.

Comment: The relevant case in Poskim is almost exclusively an Israeli listening to a Diasporan, because a Diasporan listening to an Israeli would still need another cup for his Kiddush so why bother?

Comment: It's also interesting to consider the case of Shabbat Second Day Yom Tov (eg. Shavuot). While the blessings are the same in that case, the obligations are distinct since the Israeli is only saying Havdala for Shabbat.

Comment: @DoubleAA well yes, but maybe the Diasporan (great word!) already made kiddush and forgot havdalah and would have needed another cup anyway.

Comment: @DoubleAA ooh didn't even think of that!  Yes that's a good one.

Comment: Looks like a dupe of https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/56493/5275. I can't vote though, as that question has no upvotes, yet.

Comment: I think not. Of course, the blessing on the candle is identical and there is overlap in the wording, the key factor is that it is a different type of havdalah for each one. For the "Galut"zianer (cute, huh?), the havdalah distinguishes between various levels of kedusha, but for the Israeli, it distinguishes between holy and profane. That's besides the fact that the end of the bracha is actually different. Perhaps, the Israeli can listen to the rest of the bracha, but still needs to say his own ending.

Comment: @DoubleAA Got you covered, see R. Betzalel Stern in [vol. 1 §22 no. 9](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1808&st=&pgnum=63&hilite=) quoting Sdei Chemed